# How to avoid hardcoding full URL of an xml file?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am bound to provide  a full URL : www.abc.com/folder1/folder2/my.xml  rathar than just giving relative URL "./my.xml" .

How can i solve this ? This forces me to hardcode the URL inside the .as file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand what you actually need: relative or absolute URL?

If relative, use it. Just consider that it should be relevant to the HTML wrapper, not the SWF itself.

If absolute and you just do not want to embed it into the code, pass it to your SWF from the HTML wrapper using FlashVars.

Comment: I need "Relative" URL. But the html wrapper cannot access ( and thus does not load the xml file) it when i try to test it live on the site. No problem, in local testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative url in the flash, and the fact that it's working when you test locally indicates a problem with the embed. My guess is that you have placed the swf in a subfolder from the html page but not specified a base url when embedding the swf. Is the swf file located in www.abc.com/folder1/folder2/ or any other folder other than the html itself?

If so, you need to tell the flash player which url all relative url:s in the flash should use as a starting point. This is done using the "base" parameter. If you embed the swf using SWFObject you specify it with an object with a base property:

```
var flashvars = {
};

var params = {
  base: "/folder1/folder2/"
};

var attributes = {
};

swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Note that I assumed that the .swf is in folder2/ in the example above.

Hope this solves your problem.